# Java JDK 11 - JRE not recognized by external application

Tags: java

I understand that the Oracle Java Development Kit 11 (JDK) does no longer include a public JRE (Java Runtime Environment). However the documentation says it includes a private one (I actually don't understand what that means).

I installed the JDK 11 on Windows 10 64x according to the documentation and set the path system variable accordingly. When I type

> java -version

at the command line I get informed that there is indeed a runtime environment in place.

However, when I now try to install e.g. a Plugin (Zotero) for LibreOffice that needs a JRE, it is NOT recognized ...
Why does this happen? Do I really need to install the separate JRE from Oracle to get it work?

I read the manual and the migration guide - sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm stuck.

Thank you!

Andi

Comment: The Java 11 runtime environment has a very different structure to that of Java 8 and earlier versions. I would guess that the plugin doesn't recognise Java 11 because it may be looking for specific parts which don't exist or are in a different place in Java 11. Try installing Java 8 instead. You can keep the two versions on the same machine at the same time.

Comment: A number of directories and JARs no longer exist in Java 9+ however some software assumes they are there. Until they support Java 11, I would stay with Java 8.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification! Installing JRE 8 in addition to JDK 11 works fine. Unfortunately, it seems that I cannot mark a comment as answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a user-level software configuration issue, not a programming problem.